# Pandas adding extra row to DataFrame when assigning index

Tags: python, pandas, indexing, row, dataframe

I'm trying to use the 0th column ("Gene.name") as the Index values. Here's the original data below:
[image]

I tried to set the index a few different ways.  The first was using `index_col=0` in the `DataFrame` creation.  I also tried `DF_mutations.index = DF_mutations["Gene.name"]` but they both led to an empty row underneath the header show below:
[image]

**How can I get rid of this extra row when I'm reassigning the index values?**

Comment: So you do not want a name for the `index`? The empty row is because of the index's name

Comment: The name isn't necessary, I can do away with it. How can you drop the index name once you reassign it?

Comment: I don't think there is actually an empty row in the DataFrame itself.  There is just an empty row in the display.  You don't need to get rid of the name unless you actually care about that visual display.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The empty row in the print you see is because the `index` has a name - `Gene.name` (This is not a real row in the DataFrame though) . If you don't want that row , I believe you would need to do away with the name. Example -

```
df.index.name = None
```

Demo -

```
In [6]: df = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]]).set_index(0)

In [7]: df
Out[7]:
   1  2  3
0 <-------------------------- Name of the index for this DataFrame
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4

In [10]: df.index.name=None

In [11]: df
Out[11]:
   1  2  3
1  2  3  4
1  2  3  4
```